# too many JAR files after importing play 2.5 application eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I followed the documentation at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE for importing a Play Application into Eclipse. After that, the project in the project explorer lists a lot of JAR-files, see screenshot [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL7PA.png).

In a video I saw, this was not the case. What am I doing wrong and how to correct it? How did others get the compact list of just the necessary  folders

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see a problem here. Play Framework is a *framework* - you get nice abstractions but as with every framework there is a price to pay - lot's of libraries: Play itself, Akka, Twirl, Jackson, Apache Commons, Log4j, etc. - these are all the base of Play and you shouldn't be worried.

Here is a screenshot of a freshly imported Play 2.5 project in IntelliJ (based on the simple play-java Activator template):

[image: IntelliJ JARs]

Answer (score -1):

I have same issue and I hide it in Eclipse. Do you see the key word `Referenced Libraries` in documentation picture.

They hide those `*.jar` files.

There is my answer. Please see the two picture. Click `White` inverted triangle in right top.

In Java, check show Refrenced Libraries Node
[image: a]

In Java EE, check Customize View → Libaries from external
[image: b]